# How can I send the student to moodle course URL with auto-login at Moodle interface

Tags: moodle, moodle-api, moodle-mobile

We are setting up a learning platform with Moodle. We have an existing student portal and want to send students to Moodle to attend the courses (course will be listed in the student profile in our project).

How can I send the student to moodle course URL and auto-login? Ideally, when students enter the module we don't want he/she don't' navigate away unaware, insted just finish the course (we may show the course in an iframe or popup).

We need to login via API or some other means because we wish the student to continue if he/she is reattempting.

Answer (score 0):

How do students log into the existing student portal?

Could you use SSO?

CAS and LDAP are built into Moodle

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Managing_authentication

I would also recommend the SAML2 plugin, developed by Catalyst

https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2

You might also be able to use LTI. So a user can access a course from your student portal without needing to log in.

https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/LTI_and_Moodle